# Using RGraph for iPhone data plot

Tags: iphone, html, core-plot

I am using CorePlot for plotting data graph on iPhone. Recently I encountered [RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/) based on html5 technology. CorePlot is a little over complicated for my purpose.  Does anybody have the experience for using RGraph on iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate a [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and pour your (HTML5) web content into the web view.

Comment: Thanks. Do you like the plotting library? Any thing I should pay attention to adopt this tool?

Comment: I haven't used it, but if it is HTML5, you should be able to load it into a web view. Try opening the examples with Mobile Safari to make sure the graphs work as advertised.